# <p> tag won't stay on hovered state even when hovering over it

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a `<p>` tag, and when I hover over it I want it to play an animation with @keyframes. It does the animation perfectly, but when the animation has finished, it will revert back to the state before the hovering. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: If you'd rather use a fiddle, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Whitevan_Candyman/45e7u/) out.
The reason why the buttons flash red is purely for testing reasons.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<div id="imgOver9" class="imgOver">
     <p id="pLink9" class="pLink" href="home.html">Chillin', relaxin', maxin' all cool and shootin' some b-ball outside of school</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS for the `<p>` element:

```
.pLink{
    position:absolute;
    left:1vw;
    top:-1vw;
    height:24vw;
    width:24vw;
    opacity:0;

    text-align:justify;

    display:block;

    font-family: 'Antic Didone', 'serif';

    z-index:1;

    background-color:red;

    font-size:2vw;
}

.pLink:hover{
  animation: pLink linear 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin:;
  -webkit-animation: pLink linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 10;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: pLink linear 0.1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: pLink linear 0.1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: pLink linear 0.1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;
}

@keyframes pLink{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    color:#000000
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    color:#8C8C96;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes pLink{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    color:#000000
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    color:#8C8C96;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes pLink {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    color:#000000
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    color:#8C8C96;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes pLink {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    color:#000000
  }
  100% {
opacity:1;
color:#8C8C96;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes pLink {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
    color:#000000
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
    color:#8C8C96;
  }
}
```

And here is the CSS for the parent div:

```
.imgOver{
    opacity:0%;
    width:26vw;
    height:26vw;

}
.imgOver:hover{
  animation: imgOver linear 0.1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: ;
  -webkit-animation: imgOver linear 0.1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: ;
  -moz-animation: imgOver linear 0.1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: ;
  -o-animation: imgOver linear 0.1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: ;
  -ms-animation: imgOver linear 0.1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: ;

}

@keyframes imgOver{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imgOver{
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes imgOver {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes imgOver {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes imgOver {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

I have been going over this for hours now, and I cannot find the flaw. I would be very grateful for whoever manages to solve my issue.

Comment: What's VW - font-size:2vw; ?

Comment: Can you add a JSFIDDLE link as well please?

Comment: That's exactly what an animation does. I'm thinking that you either want a transition or a permanent style change on hover, in the latter case, you would need Js/JQ.

Comment: @dipaks, I am not entirely sure, but I believe `vw` stands for "Viewport width". More info [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Comment: @manu, I'll get to it right away.

Comment: @Paulie_D, if that is the case, then the parent div should also revert back to its original (not white) state, however it does not do so. It behaves exactly like I want it to behave.

Comment: @manu, I added a fiddle.

Comment: thanks, will have a look @TobyvanKempen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `animation: pLink 0.1s forwards;` in order to keep the final state of the animation.

Here is a demo **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaSLe/)**

Comment: Sweet baby jesus, that's exactly what I want. Words cannot describe how grateful I am!